# How to "Debug Windows Phone Internet Explorer" in VS2015?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

In VS2013 Update 2, there was an option added to the `Debug > Other Debug Targets` menu that allowed you to start a mobile Internet Explorer session on a physical, USB-connected Windows Phone device with a specified URL. AFAIK, this was the only way to debug a website on a real device.

In VS2015 Update 1 this menuitem is no longer there. Does VS2015 no longer support this feature, or is there an additional package I need to install (and if so, what)?

Note that this isn't a question about WP emulators - unfortunately, my site works fine in those, but not so much on the actual device I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed updated 1 yesterday and i can still see that menu you are looking for. You can try press CTRL+SHIFT+P , if you didn't do this already, or you can reinstall/change Update 1 (Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > View Installed updates  and  see what version of update on VS 2015 you have).

Read this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P does nothing. After an hour of repairing, the menuitem still isn't there, and Ctrl+Shift+P still does nothing. This isn't the first time I've had such nonsense with VS2015, it really seems that Microsoft's quality control is slipping.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+P is the shortcut to open that menu . Thanks for for pointing my answer unuseful. Maybe if you read all that link, you`ll see that you need to be up to date with your windows as well. good luck with that ...